# Calculate area of Map in miles on Zoom Level

Tags: android

I am new in android, I want to know how can I calculate the area of a Map in miles on Zoom Level, so that I can call my web service and make a marker according to the distance of my current location.

Answer (score 0):

Your question slightly confusing, area and distance are two different things.

Use the Location.distanceTo function to calculate distance between two points on the map.

```
OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);

GeoPoint mPoint = item.getPoint();  // get Point of your marker

Location locationMy = m_MyLocationOverlay.getLastFix();  // get current location
if (locationMy != null)
{
     Location locationPoint = new Location(locationMy);
     locationPoint.setLatitude((double)mPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1000000.0f);
     locationPoint.setLongitude((double)mPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1000000.0f);
     String str = String.format("%.1f miles", locationMy.distanceTo(locationPoint) * 0.000621371192);   // meters to miles
}
```